# Grouping according to date (ID) and creating 3 new columns from the group value and group names in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, dplyr

**Dear altruists,**
I got stuck at this stage of my data cleaning. I have a data frame like this. I want to create 3 new columns like those shown in the code below.
Would you mind helping me out in this regard? Thanks in advance for your valuable time!

```
id <- c(rep("1", 3), rep("1", 3), rep("2", 3), rep("2", 3), rep("2", 3), rep("3", 3), rep("3", 3))
date <- c(rep("17-10-2010", 3), rep("20-11-2010", 3), rep("23-12-2010", 3), rep("25-01-2011", 3), rep("27-02-2011", 3), rep("30-03-2011", 3), rep("05-04-2011", 3))
score <- c(rep(1, 3), rep(4, 3), rep(4, 3), rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3), rep(5, 3), rep(1, 3))

df <- data.frame(id, date, score)
df
#>    id       date score
#> 1   1 17-10-2010     1
#> 2   1 17-10-2010     1
#> 3   1 17-10-2010     1
#> 4   1 20-11-2010     4
#> 5   1 20-11-2010     4
#> 6   1 20-11-2010     4
#> 7   2 23-12-2010     4
#> 8   2 23-12-2010     4
#> 9   2 23-12-2010     4
#> 10  2 25-01-2011     1
#> 11  2 25-01-2011     1
#> 12  2 25-01-2011     1
#> 13  2 27-02-2011     2
#> 14  2 27-02-2011     2
#> 15  2 27-02-2011     2
#> 16  3 30-03-2011     5
#> 17  3 30-03-2011     5
#> 18  3 30-03-2011     5
#> 19  3 05-04-2011     1
#> 20  3 05-04-2011     1
#> 21  3 05-04-2011     1
df1 <- df %>% group_by(date) %>% mutate(Diff = score - lag(score))
#> Error in df %>% group_by(date) %>% mutate(Diff = score - lag(score)): could not find function "%>%"
df1
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'df1' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

*But I want to have something like this from where I want to subset only for **Diff >= 3 | Diff <= -3**:

```
id <- c("1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3")
date <- c("17-10-2010", "20-11-2010", "23-12-2010", "25-01-2011", "27-02-2011", "30-03-2011", "05-04-2011")
score <- c(1, 4, 4, 1, 2, 5, 1)
Diff <- c(NA, 3, NA, -3, 1, NA, -4)
previous_date <- c("", "17-10-2010", "", "23-12-2010", "25-01-2011", "", "30-03-2011")
last_date <- c("17-10-2010", "20-11-2010", "23-12-2010", "25-01-2011", "27-02-2011", "30-03-2011", "05-04-2011")
df2 <- data.frame(id, date, score, Diff, previous_date, last_date)
df2
#>   id       date score Diff previous_date  last_date
#> 1  1 17-10-2010     1   NA               17-10-2010
#> 2  1 20-11-2010     4    3    17-10-2010 20-11-2010
#> 3  2 23-12-2010     4   NA               23-12-2010
#> 4  2 25-01-2011     1   -3    23-12-2010 25-01-2011
#> 5  2 27-02-2011     2    1    25-01-2011 27-02-2011
#> 6  3 30-03-2011     5   NA               30-03-2011
#> 7  3 05-04-2011     1   -4    30-03-2011 05-04-2011
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be enough:

```r
df1 <-
    df %>% select(id,date,score) %>% unique %>%
    group_by( id ) %>%
    mutate(Diff = score - lag(score), prevous_date = lag(date) ) %>%
    filter( !is.na(Diff) & abs(Diff) >= 3 )
```

This is what I get:

```
  id    date       score  Diff previous_date
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        
1 1     20-11-2010     4     3 17-10-2010   
2 2     25-01-2011     1    -3 23-12-2010   
3 3     05-04-2011     1    -4 30-03-2011
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution, @Sirius. It is almost correct. The issue is I wanted not to subtract score of one ID by another. The 3rd row of your result is like this, which is the difference of ID 2 and ID 3. Scores of same ID in two different dates should be subtracted. That's why the first observation (at the first date) of a particular ID has no score difference (Diff) or previous_date. And I also need the corresponding date of the differences in two new columns. And then comes the subsetting. Would you mind helping me in this regard?

Comment: It worked for the Difference! Thanks a lot! But I could not get the logic on how to make two columns for the dates. Would you mind having a look at it?

Comment: Of course, sloppy of me. See the update. `last_date` is just the same as `date`, right? add ` %>% rename( last_date = date )` if you need it with that name.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. There is a small typo, just. "Date" will be "date". Otherwise it is all ok now. Know my gratitude for your cordial help.